# Default color scheme Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In [this](https://sanjibsinha.com/color-flutter/) tutorial author show how to prepare new ColorScheme:

```
const ColorScheme _customColorScheme = ColorScheme(
  primary: customMagenta50,
  primaryVariant: customMagenta600,
  secondary: Colors.amber,
  secondaryVariant: customMagenta400,
  surface: Colors.purpleAccent,
  background: customSurfaceWhite,
  error: customMagenta900,
  onPrimary: Colors.red,
  onSecondary: Colors.deepOrange,
  onSurface: customMagenta300,
  onBackground: customMagenta100,
  onError: Colors.redAccent,
  brightness: Brightness.light,
);
```

A lot of parameters are required in this constructor. Where I can find default colours used in default light theme? I want use code as above and change only one or two values (another values I change at next phase of my project).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply changes to the default light ColorScheme like so:

```dart
final ColorScheme _colorScheme = ColorScheme.light().copyWith(->your changes<-);
```

Comment: Thank You, in my case ` ColorScheme.light().copyWith(` is the best option!

Answer (score 4):

You can check the source-code on GitHub. For default  [light colorSchema](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/1d84805c754e94c33423f767173a5ed462dabf92/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/color_scheme.dart#L248-L318)

You can use `copyWith` constructor.

```dart
 return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(
          //..here 
        )
      ),
```

An easy way to find attributes by pressing `ctrl+space` while you are inside the `copyWith(..here.)` method

[image]

You can find more details on flutter.dev > [ColorScheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html).